# How do I get my C program to run into the OUTPUT window?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal, output

I was making a program about leap years, and it turns out the code runs in the TERMINAL perfectly.
[Here is the picture with the respective program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ah3.png)

The problem is I don't know how to run it in the OUTPUT window.

Whenever I try to not use the integrated terminal by unticking the Run In Terminal option, this happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hXvv.png)

[The code is stuck on still running, no matter how long it takes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijDcv.png)

Why is it happening? I'd like to receive some help about it, if it is possible to run the whole program in the OUTPUT window. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the problematic code to the post (not as an image?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code/other textual information. Post them as text/formatted code blocks

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  Assuming that you are using an IDE and the 'output window' is a window of the IDE, we should be able to tell which IDE you're using without having to look at the images.  If you aren't using an IDE, you need to explain what you mean by 'the output window'.  Specifying the platform, at least to Linux vs Windows, might help too.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How is he supposed to distinguish between windows in a GUI application by posting text?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2022
The output Window is for the output of the IDE, such as the compiler output. Your program's output should not appear there.

Comment: @Barmar Pasting the code as text is the very least that can be done. I said *textual information*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That may be true, although the code is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure about that. It sounded to me like a UB that is manifesting when run in IDE console, but not in terminal

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, it's just the normal `printf()` output, they want it in a different window of the IDE.

Comment: Just a quick look (based on what MooingDuck said): In your third/last image, the `OUTPUT` window is highlighted. Try clicking on `TERMINAL` to get the program's output and give it input. I don't think you _can_ get your program's output to go to `OUTPUT`. Since `TERMINAL` works, _why_ do you want it to go to `OUTPUT`?